# search for unresolved references that should have been ifdef'ed out

Tags: c++

I hope this is an interesting question.  I'm trying to find the source of an unresolved external symbol.  I have debug code that uses a global file pointer if debugging is turned on.  All of this debugging code is supposed to be protected by #ifdef, like:

```
#ifdef DO_XLL_DEBUG
fprintf(debugPointer, "hello\n);
...
#endif
```

When I define DO_XLL_DEBUG, all is well. If I undef DO_XLL_DEBUG, everything compiles (I do a rebuild all just in case), but it fails at the link step, not finding debugPointer.

So, the question is, is there an easy way to find where I failed to #ifdef around the debug code? I can think of several not so easy ways.

I'm using Visual Studio 2005.  This is a C++ project.

Thanks!

[EDIT]

Thanks for all the suggestions.  Turns out the problem was in someone else's code that is not part the corresponding project I'm working on in Linux (where I do most of my work), so no wonder I didn't find it right away.

Comment: Have you looked at the complete output from the linker? I am not familiar with the VS toolchain, but many linkers will tell you where the symbol was referenced from.

Comment: Instead of cluttering your code with a thousand `#ifdef`s why don't you just `#ifdef` the function itself to nothing in a release build?  This would be the canonical way to do it.  Anyway, if it's a linker error then it's the definition that it can't find.

Comment: @EdS., debugging output `printf` style isn't easy to turn into a macro function because of the variable number of parameters.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Just call `vfprintf` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define some incompatible `debugPointer` and let the compiler point you at all the places where it's accidentially used or redefined. Maybe like this:

```
#ifndef DO_XLL_DEBUG
#define debugPointer static_assert(false,"damn it!");
#endif
```

(given that you don't have other variables, parameters, etc. which are called `debugPointer`)

Comment: This is especially easy in Visual Studio because you can add it to the precompiled header file commonly called `stdafx.h`.

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.  I've done that sort of thing in the past but apparently I'm suffering from brain freeze or something.